# Spring Cache to Disable Cache by cacheName configuration

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I am using spring boot, and it's very easy to integrate spring cache with other cache component.

By caching data, we can use `@Cachable` annotation, but still we need configure and add cacheName to the `cacheManager`, without this step, we will get an exception while accessing the method:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'xxxx' for Builder`

My question is, is that able to disable the cache instead of raising the error if we not configure the `cacheName`? I raised this because spring cache provide a configuration `spring.cache.cacheNames` in `CacheProperties`.

Not sure if the `condition` attribute in `@Cachable` works for this.

Any idea is appreciate!!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your "caching provider" and the implementation of the [CacheManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) interface, in particular.  Since Spring's [Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-strategies) is just that, an "abstraction" it allows you to plugin different providers and backend data stores to support the caches required by your application (i.e. as determined by Spring's caching annotations, or alternatively, the JSR-107-JCache annotations; see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-jsr-107-summary)).

For instance, if you were to use the Spring Framework's provided [`ConcurrentMapCacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheManager.html) implementation (not recommended for production except for really simple UCs), then if you choose to **not** declare your caches at configuration/initialization time (using the [default, no-arg constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheManager.html#ConcurrentMapCacheManager--)) then the "`Caches`" are lazily created.  However, if you do declare your "`Caches`" at configuration/initialization time (using the [constructor accepting cache name arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheManager.html#ConcurrentMapCacheManager-java.lang.String...-)), then if your application uses a cache (e.g. `@Cacheable("NonExistingCache")`) not explicitly declared, then Exception would be thrown because the [`getCache(name:String):Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheManager.html#getCache-java.lang.String-) method would return `null` and the `CacheInterceptor` initialization logic would [throw an `IllegalArgumentException`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L252-L257) for no `Cache` available for the caching operation (follow from the `CacheIntercepter` down, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheInterceptor.java#L61), [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L317), [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L236), [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L675) and then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java#L220-L230)).

There is no way to disable this initialization check (i.e. throw Exception) for non-existing caches, currently.  The best you can do is, like the `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` implementation, lazily create `Caches`.  However, this heavily depends on your caching provider implementation.  Obviously, some cache providers are more sophisticated than others and creating a `Cache` on the fly (i.e. lazily) is perhaps more expensive and costly, so is not supported by the caching provider, or not recommended.

Still, you could work around this limitation by wrapping any `CacheManager` implementation (of your choice), and delegate to the underlying implementation for "existing" `Caches` and "safely" handle "non-existing" `Caches` by treating it as a Cache miss simply by providing some simple wrapper implementations of the core Spring `CacheManager` and `Cache` interfaces.

Here is an [example integration test class](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/cache/DeclaredCachesConcurrentMapCacheManagerIntegrationTests.java) that demonstrates your current problem.  Note the [test/assertions](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/cache/DeclaredCachesConcurrentMapCacheManagerIntegrationTests.java#L74-L87) for non-existing `Caches`.

Then, here is an [example integration test class](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/cache/NonExistingCacheSafeCacheManagerWrapperIntegrationTests.java) that demonstrates how to effectively disable caching for non-existing `Caches` (not provided by the caching provider).  Once again, note the [test/assertions](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/cache/NonExistingCacheSafeCacheManagerWrapperIntegrationTests.java#L74-L82) for safely accessing non-existing `Caches`.

This is made possible by the [wrapper delegate](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/cache/NonExistingCacheSafeCacheManagerWrapperIntegrationTests.java#L122-L149) for `CacheManager` (which wraps and delegates to an existing caching provider, which in this case is just the `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` again (see [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/cache/NonExistingCacheSafeCacheManagerWrapperIntegrationTests.java#L88-L92)), but would work for any caching provider supported by Spring *Cache Abstraction*) along with the [`NoOpNamedCache` implementation](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/tests-example/src/test/java/example/tests/spring/cache/NonExistingCacheSafeCacheManagerWrapperIntegrationTests.java#L122-L200) of the Spring `Cache` interface.  This no-op `Cache` instance could be a *Singleton* and reused for all non-existing `Caches` if you did not care about the name.  But, it would give you a degree of visibility into which "named" `Caches` are not configured with an actual `Cache` since this most likely will have an impact on your services (i.e. service methods without caching enabled because the "named" cache does not exist).

Anyway, this may not be one you exactly want, and I would even caution you to take special care if you pushed this to production since (I'd argue) it really ought to fail fast for missing `Caches`, but this does achieve what you want.

Clearly, it is configurable and you could make it conditional based on cache name or other criteria, in that, if your really don't care or don't want caching on certain service methods in certain contexts, then it is up to you and this approach is flexible and completely give you that choice, if needed.

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I just wonder that makes the configuration redundant. Now, I know what I can do.

Comment: Fantastic, this is what I ended up doing. Shame that Spring doesn't allow that to be configured or just warn on missing cache instead of blowing up everything. I am thinking of a scenario where you end up calling a @Cachable annotated service at runtime but don't have cache defined for that key. Anyway this solution works for that case.